# SQL - YTD and MTD in rows instead of columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have this table:

| FiscalPeriod | FiscalMonth | FiscalYear | Division | L4 | L5 | L6 | L7 | AMT_LEGAL_USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | A | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | A | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 2000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | A | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 2000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | B | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | B | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 3000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | B | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 5000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | C | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | C | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 1000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | C | NOP | OP | GM | NS | 1000 |

I'm trying to build a table that queries this one and calculates MTD (month to date) and YTD (Year to Date): for each Division, caculate the MTD and YTD based on FiscalMonth and FiscalYear columns, for each of my KPIs (columns L4 to L7)

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    ec.FiscalPeriod, 
    ec.FiscalMonth, 
    ec.FiscalYear, 
    ec.Divison,
    sum(CASE WHEN L7 = 'NS' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as NS_MTD,
    sum(NS_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Divison ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS NS_YTD,
    sum(CASE WHEN L6 = 'GM' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as GM_MTD,
    sum(GM_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Divison ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS GM_YTD,
    sum(CASE WHEN L5 = 'OP' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as OP_MTD,
    sum(OP_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Divison ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS OP_YTD,
    sum(CASE WHEN L4 = 'NOP' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as NOP_MTD,
    sum(NOP_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Divison ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS NOP_YTD,
from my table ec
    group by 1,2,3,4
    having Net_Sales_MTD != 0 and GM_MTD != 0 and OP_MTD != 0 and NOP_MTD != 0
    order by 1 asc;
```

That will return me something like:

| FiscalPeriod | FiscalMonth | FiscalYear | Division | NS_MTD | NS_YTD | GM_MTD | GM_YTD | OP_MTD | OP_YTD | NOP_MTD | NOP_YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | A | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | A | 2000 | 3000 | 2000 | 3000 | 2000 | 3000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | A | 2000 | 5000 | 2000 | 5000 | 2000 | 5000 | 2000 | 5000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | B | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | B | 3000 | 4000 | 3000 | 4000 | 3000 | 4000 | 3000 | 4000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | B | 5000 | 9000 | 5000 | 9000 | 5000 | 9000 | 5000 | 9000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | C | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 2000 | 1000 | 3000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | C | 1000 | 2000 | 1000 | 2000 | 1000 | 2000 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | C | 1000 | 3000 | 1000 | 3000 | 1000 | 3000 | 1000 | 3000 |

I would like to get an output that would look like:

| FiscalPeriod | FiscalMonth | FiscalYear | Division | Period | NOP | OP | GM | NS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | A | MTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | A | YTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | A | MTD | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | A | YTD | 3000 | 3000 | 3000 | 3000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | A | MTD | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | A | YTD | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | B | MTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | B | YTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | B | MTD | 3000 | 3000 | 3000 | 3000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | B | YTD | 4000 | 4000 | 4000 | 4000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | B | MTD | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | B | YTD | 9000 | 9000 | 9000 | 9000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | C | MTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 01-2022 | 1 | 2022 | C | YTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | C | MTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 2022 | C | YTD | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | C | MTD | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 03-2022 | 3 | 2022 | C | YTD | 3000 | 3000 | 3000 | 3000 |

Any ideas on how this can be achivied? Hopefully that wasn't too confusing.

Appreciate any feedback and ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to do this in two steps:

1. Calculate MTD
2. Calculate YTD
3. Union All

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9dc9cca14f90b0dcd53ee0383dc9f399) is an example based on your data.

```
with mtd as (
    SELECT
        ec.FiscalPeriod, 
        ec.FiscalMonth, 
        ec.FiscalYear, 
        ec.Division,
        'MTD' as Period,
        sum(CASE WHEN L7 = 'NS' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as NS_MTD,
        sum(CASE WHEN L6 = 'GM' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as GM_MTD,
        sum(CASE WHEN L5 = 'OP' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as OP_MTD,
        sum(CASE WHEN L4 = 'NOP' then EC.AMT_LEGAL_USD else 0 end) as NOP_MTD
    from data ec
    group by 1,2,3,4    
)
, ytd as (
    SELECT
        ec.FiscalPeriod, 
        ec.FiscalMonth, 
        ec.FiscalYear, 
        ec.Division,
        'YTD' as Period,
        sum(NS_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Division ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS NS_YTD,
        sum(GM_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Division ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS GM_YTD,
        sum(OP_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Division ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS OP_YTD,
        sum(NOP_MTD) OVER (PARTITION BY ec.FiscalYear, ec.Division ORDER BY ec.FiscalPeriod) AS NOP_YTD
    from mtd ec
    group by 1,2,3,4, NS_MTD, gm_mtd, op_mtd, op_mtd, nop_mtd
)
   
select * from (
   select * from mtd 
   union all 
   select * from ytd
) foo
order by fiscalyear, division, fiscalperiod, fiscalmonth, period
```